# Installing R gsl package on Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux

I am failing to install the R package gsl on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I don't understand what the problem is.

From within R:

```
> install.packages('gsl')
* installing *source* package ‘gsl’ ...
** package ‘gsl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gsl-config... /usr/bin/gsl-config
checking if GSL version >= 2.1... checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
configure: error: Need GSL version >= 1.16
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’
* removing ‘/home/luca_ph/R/lib/R/library/gsl’
```

It sais it needs gsl version >= 1.16, however I have it installed:

```
dpkg -s libgsl-dev | grep Version
Version: 2.4+dfsg-6
```

Also, gsl-config is available in the $PATH (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318885/linux-gsl-r-package-installation-gsl-config-not-found-even-though-the-external).

I tried to pass the appropiate compiler arguments to R when calling it (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781125/installing-r-gsl-package-on-mac)), however it fails all the same:

```
> gsl-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
> gsl-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
> CFLAGS="-I/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm" R
> install.packages('gsl')
[...]
* installing *source* package ‘gsl’ ...
** package ‘gsl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gsl-config... /usr/bin/gsl-config
checking if GSL version >= 2.1... checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
configure: error: Need GSL version >= 1.16
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it help to install `libgsl2` as well?

Comment: you could try installing the binary with `apt install r-cran-gsl` (after setting up the [c2d4u ppa](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)

Comment: thanks, both of you, however, it doesn't help.
@r2evans No, unfortunatley not. According to `apt install libgsl2-dev` the pacakge was replaced by libgslcblas0. And libgslcblas0 is already installed...
@user20650: i can install it using 'apt install r-cran-gsl', however, it just doesn't change anything to my problem... :/

Comment: The presence of  `GSL version >= 1.16`  & `GSL version >= 2.1` suggests you have two gsl versions installed, prior to gsl 2.4 for  >=1.16 requirement, so perhaps `sudo locate gsl-config` gives two paths.

Comment: @Chris no, it only gives one path... :  /usr/bin/gsl-config

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 18):

Despite the error message, R package `gsl` now requires GSL version >= 2.5 (see [here](https://github.com/RobinHankin/gsl/issues/17)).  Even though I was able to install the most recent version of GSL (2.7), I wasn't knowledgeable enough to follow the advice in the INSTALL file of the R package:

> If the gsl R package builds successfully but will not load, make sure to inform your system linker/loader where to find the GSL libraries used to compile it.  That step may be missed when using a manual GSL installation as opposed to one performed by a package manager.

So I opted to use the PPA repo linked to in the [How to get GNU software](https://www.gnu.org/software/software.html#HowToGetSoftware) webpage which had GSL version 2.5 available.

In short, I ran these commands to overcome the issue you describe:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dns/gnu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libgsl-dev
```

Not 100% sure if this is generally applicable, but I also had to remove the previous version of GSL with the `sudo apt remove` command before installing the newer version.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 and this solved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well, Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon (Ubuntu 18.04).