# ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’

Tags: r

I am trying to install R package gsl and I get

```
configure: error: Need GSL version >= 1.16
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gsl’
```

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583193/installing-r-gsl-package-on-ubuntu), but the solution suggested there didn't work and I don't know where to look for the cause of the problem.

I am working on Ubuntu. I have GSL version 2.3

```
gsl-config --version
2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this online and it worked (signature from the original poster):

> 1. download the source package
> 2. uncompress/unarchive the package
> 3. delete the 2 configure scripts
> 4. in src, rename Makevars.in Makevars
> 5. edit Makevars, replace @GSL_CFLAGS@ with the output of 'gsl-config —cflags’ and replace @GSL_LIBS@ with the output of ‘gsl-config —libs'
> 6. R CMD INSTALL the gsl directory
>
> Hope that works,
> Kjell

There are also instructions in the manual of the package (for version 2.1-7.1 they are on page 33). The 2 sets of instructions are very similar, but those from the manual alone didn't work for me.

This is how my Makevars file looks like

> GSL_CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include

> GSL_LIBS   = -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

> #combine to standard arguments for R

> #PKG_CPPFLAGS =  $(GSL_CFLAGS) -I.

> #PKG_LIBS = $(GSL_LIBS)

> PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

> PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include